# val_accuracy not changing in Keras CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to make a binary classification model using keras.

I have a dataset that has 2400 images, 1200 for each class, so i have tried to augment that data.

Here's my model:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=40,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')

dataset_tr = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        dataset_dir + "/test", 
        target_size=(160, 160),  
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')  

dataset_vl = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        dataset_dir + "/val",
        target_size=(160, 160),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

def model1(kernelsize = 3):

  model = Sequential()

  model.add(Rescaling(1./225, input_shape=(160,160,3)))

  model.add(Conv2D(32, kernelsize, padding='same', activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())

  model.add(Conv2D(32, kernelsize, padding='same', activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())

  model.add(Conv2D(64, kernelsize, padding='same', activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())

  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))

  model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

  model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
  model.summary()

  return model

model1 = model1()
history1 = model1.fit(dataset_tr, validation_data=dataset_vl, epochs=15)


Results: Model: "sequential_13"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 rescaling_13 (Rescaling)    (None, 160, 160, 3)       0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_42 (Conv2D)          (None, 160, 160, 32)      896       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_42 (MaxPoolin  (None, 80, 80, 32)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_9 (Batc  (None, 80, 80, 32)       128       
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 conv2d_43 (Conv2D)          (None, 80, 80, 32)        9248      
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_43 (MaxPoolin  (None, 40, 40, 32)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_10 (Bat  (None, 40, 40, 32)       128       
 chNormalization)                                                
                                                                 
 conv2d_44 (Conv2D)          (None, 40, 40, 64)        18496     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_44 (MaxPoolin  (None, 20, 20, 64)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_11 (Bat  (None, 20, 20, 64)       256       
 chNormalization)                                                
                                                                 
 flatten_13 (Flatten)        (None, 25600)             0         
                                                                 
 dense_26 (Dense)            (None, 64)                1638464   
                                                                 
 dropout_13 (Dropout)        (None, 64)                0         
                                                                 
 dense_27 (Dense)            (None, 1)                 65        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,667,681
Trainable params: 1,667,425
Non-trainable params: 256
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/15
57/61 [===========================>..] - ETA: 17s - loss: 3.2906 - accuracy: 0.6753/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py:975: UserWarning: Palette images with Transparency expressed in bytes should be converted to RGBA images
  warnings.warn(
61/61 [==============================] - 399s 5s/step - loss: 3.1287 - accuracy: 0.6725 - val_loss: 0.7496 - val_accuracy: 0.5070
Epoch 2/15
61/61 [==============================] - 291s 5s/step - loss: 0.7012 - accuracy: 0.6843 - val_loss: 0.7872 - val_accuracy: 0.5070
Epoch 3/15
61/61 [==============================] - 294s 5s/step - loss: 0.6309 - accuracy: 0.6776 - val_loss: 0.9963 - val_accuracy: 0.5070
Epoch 4/15
61/61 [==============================] - 296s 5s/step - loss: 0.6089 - accuracy: 0.7100 - val_loss: 0.9901 - val_accuracy: 0.5070
Epoch 5/15
61/61 [==============================] - 290s 5s/step - loss: 0.5859 - accuracy: 0.7074 - val_loss: 1.1462 - val_accuracy: 0.5070
Epoch 6/15
61/61 [==============================] - 297s 5s/step - loss: 0.5830 - accuracy: 0.7059 - val_loss: 1.0407 - val_accuracy: 0.5070
```

This happened after i augmented the data. Before were changing the values, but the model were overfitting so i tried augment the data and got this.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your datagen you have the cod

```
 rescale=1./255,
```

In your model you have the code

```
model.add(Rescaling(1./225, input_shape=(160,160,3)))
```

So you are rescaling the images twice the net effect is image pixel value are scaled by 1/(255 X 255) . Remove one of the line of code mentioned above